# dbbrowser gem installation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, browser

I'm trying to install a gem called dbbrowser by following its documentation as in https://github.com/rubylibs/dbbrowser. They have given two steps

1. map '/browse' { run DbBrowser::Server  } which is added to config.ru
2. mount DbBrowser::Server, :at => '/browse' which is added to config.routes.rb

   While running the server i got this error

   /media-ps/config.ru syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)
       map '/browse' { run DbBrowser::Server  }

I tried with all possible ways to solve the syntax problem. What could be done to solve this issue ? Is there any other syntax for map and mount?

Answer (score 0):

add the following script

map  `/media-ps/config.ru '/browse' { run DbBrowser::Server }` in config.ru

```
mount '/browse' DbBrowser::Server, :at => '/browse' in  config.routes.rb
```

It will work

Comment: Tried it but got /home/sh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval': /home/sh/work/projects/a/media-ps/config.ru:4: unknown regexp options - cfg (SyntaxError)
                                                                 /home/sh/work/projects/a/media-ps/config.ru:4: syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting '}'
map /media-ps/config.ru '/browse' { run DbBrowser::Server }
                                          ^                                      /home/sh/work/projects/a/media-ps/config.ru:6: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting end-of-input
}.to_app
 ^

Comment: Thanks for yur reply Mr.Koni !! 3:)